# Merging of observables and array of strings

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I understand that `forkjoin` would need to have two observables, however, I have one observables and one array of strings. The array of strings would need to be matched to a key/value in the observables. If the value doesn't exists, then a new observable would be added based on the shape of the observable.

```
const arr = ["ABT", "ABC"]
this.http.get<[]>(`this.someUrl`,)
    .pipe(
        map((result: []) => {
            // result= {userId: "user123", symbol: "ABC", comments: "this is text"}
            return res;
        }),
    );
```

The desire would be returning an observable with

```
{userId: "user123", symbol: "ABT", comments: ""},
{userId: "user123", symbol: "ABC", comments: "this is text"}
```

How does one approach this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem. Do you want to have one notification with an array with the two objects or do you want to have only a single notification? Do you mind elaboration?

Comment: @Jan-NiklasWortmann itd be a single notification returning as a observable. The combined observable would then be called. is that clear?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are aiming for is this:

```
const arr = ["ABT", "ABC"]
this.http.get<[]>("this.someUrl",)
    .pipe(
        map((result: []) => {
            return arr.map(value => {
                const obj = result.find(a => a.symbol === value);
                if (obj) {
                   return {...result}
                } else {
                   return {...result, symbol: value, comments: ""}
                }
           });
        }),
    );
```

I still don't understand what you try to achieve, but this should mathc your expectation. This is also propably not the most performant solution for your problem.